# Connecting PSUs in parallel

Tags: power-supply, power, dc-dc-converter, ground, atx

It's certainly have been asked here but answers seems mixed. So for my project I need to power an ATX motherboard with extra 3.3V rail (there's a separate connector on MB for this). I will be using 12V DC input.

I've decided to use PicoPSU [1], however it's kind of weak on 3.3V rail and there's no easy way to get that 3.3V out of it for the second connector this motherboard requires, so I've opted out for a separate DC-DC converter [2]. I plan to wire everything as on schematic, but I have few questions:

- Do I have to put diodes between two PSUs?
- Do I need to connect two grounds at the output as well?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSt0R5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's another connection option:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f97jKv.png)</sup>

1. [PicoPSU XT 160W](https://resources.mini-box.com/online/PWR-PICOPSU-160-XT/PWR-PICOPSU-160-XT-manual.pdf).
2. [RSD-30G-3.3](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/RSD-30/RSD-30-SPEC.PDF).

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to squash a lot into a small space. No matter how simple PSU sharing seems in a block diagram sketch, it's far more difficult to actually make. Your PSU's 3V3 regulators aren't designed to share loads and the operating inaccuracies produced by ORing FETs make it unusable. Face the music, I'm afraid: find a smaller supply or accept a bigger box/arrangement. It's better than a damaged motherboard after some or no time running off some lash-up.

Comment: @TonyM yes, I'm trying to replace very old original PSU with something more modern. I'm pretty sure it has these separate 3V3 connectors wired up together inside; as for the Pico, the only 3V3 output seems to be ATX pin, which's no go. On the motherboard itself these extra 3V3 go to PCI bus, so they're kind of required

Comment: Also there's Add2PSU, I think I need smth similar on the output side (or ORing diodes)

Comment: Most SMPS buck circuits cannot sink current (1) so diodes are not needed and putting a diode on 3.3V would be pretty self defeating. You'd need to run it at 3.9V or so depending on type. You load balance would be probably way off with one or the other supply carrying most of the current. This kind of thing needs to be designed in at the PSU and it can easily lead into oscillations etc. 
(1) SyncBuck theoretically can but it's not a normal feature of the controller.

Comment: The grounds of your PSU and DC/DC converter are connected on the left side. I guarantee you that on the right side there's also a pathway between the two grounds. You also don't know what's in the ground pathway from left to right inside the PSU and if there is, that might mess things up because now it's short circuited through the common ground of your DC/DC converter. You should clear this up first.

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this.  You do not need to worry about connecting the power supply **inputs** in parallel.  As long as your 12V source is high enough quality to handle the input ripple and load transients (and of course, the total power draw), there is no issue there, and you certainly do not need diodes or anything else for that matter.

it is only power supply **outputs** that you need to worry about paralleling.
And the short answer is you can't.  The 3.3V rail will not tolerate the voltage drop from OR'ing diodes, and this would generate a lot of waste heat.  You could use load-sharing resistors, but they too would drop the voltage and would only limit, but not eliminate, currents flowing between the two paralleled 3.3V rails.  It would make both the DC/DC converter and PicoPSU heat up and possibly fail, and erode most of the extra power you were hoping to gain by paralleling them in the first place.

So just don't do that.

There is no reason you can't power each voltage rail from different supplies as long as you ensure all of their **output** grounds are well-connected to each other (and they will be through the motherboard itself regardless.  Take a multimeter, do a continuity test on the ground pins for any connectors on the motherboard - you'll see what I mean).

All you need to do is:

1. Cut all of the orange 3.3V wires coming from the PicoPSU's ATX cable as close to the PicoPSU (leaving as much wire coming from the motherboard end of the ATX cable) as possible.
2. Splice in the 3.3V output from your DC/DC converter to the now loose orange 3.3V wires going to the motherboard.
3. Wire in whatever additional connectors carrying 3.3V to your DC/DC converter as well
4. Connect the output grounds of the PicoPSU and the DC/DC converter to each other.  You want this connection to be as short and low resistance as possible.  Large, thick copper as short as is reasonable.

Of course, you will need to size the DC/DC converter accordingly so it can handle the entire 3.3V demand.  The PicoPSU's 3.3V rail shouldn't be connected at all if you did everything correctly.  This side-steps the need of paralleling the outputs entirely.  You will not get the increased power from paralleling the 3.3V rails unless you get two power supplies designed to perform load-sharing, and will have additional connections between them to facilitate communication that enables such a feature.  This is typically only seen in certain server PSUs and high-end DC/DC converters, and never ATX PSUs.  You will mostly just get a lot more heat and wasted power at best, or 1-2 dead power supplies at worst.

[image]

Comment: The PicoPSU has no cables, it's all on the PCB and then plug directly into the ATX socket, so you'd have some soldering to do.

Comment: I'm confused as to where the -12V rail comes from in the above diagram

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to put diodes between two PSUs?

No diodes are needed, diodes are used with power supplies to prevent the reversal of current, this happens if one voltage on one side of the diode would be lower than the other side (like if one supply went down or was disconnected). As long as both supplies are powered at the same time from the same 12V supply, it should be fine not to use diodes in the design

> Do I need to connect two grounds at the output as well?

Yes, the meanwell supply (RSD-30) is an *isolated supply*. This means the output will make whatever is on the plus rail 3.3V higher than the negative rail. (so if the negative rail is grounded, the supply generates 3.3V with respect to ground, if you tied the negative end (V-) of the RSD-30 to 5V, you would have 8.3V on the V+ rail).

[image]
Source: https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/RSD-30/RSD-30-SPEC.PDF

The problem is that if you connect anything between the supplies with one supply being isolated (like a digital communication line), it could create unforseen voltage differences.

If you aren't going to connect loads together (running digital lines from devices on one supply to the other) from both supplies, then you could leave the 3.3V supply isolated.

If you are connecting the loads together or if you are unsure (running digital lines from devices on one supply to the other) then you should connect the V- output of the RSD-30 to the ground of the system.

Connecting the grounds could be done a few ways.

Option 1 is connecting a wire from the I/P- terminal to the V- terminal on the RSD-30, this is easier but it if you have a lot of change in power it could create more noise.

Option 2 would be better because any common mode noise from cabling (current through the resistance of the cable would be lessened by tying the grounds together at the PICO supply or motherboard (if you could find a grounding spot on the mobo that might also work)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1HOm7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is there any concern regarding loads being parallel? Are you sure I don't need to explicitly isolate them like @metacollin specified above?

Comment: Is the 3.3v going to the motherboard or a separate load? If going to a separate load then it doesn't matter. If you are trying to parallel the 3.3v line for extra current (first check to make sure you would need extra current on the 3.3v line by looking at the motherboard specs and any cards or devices you might add) you will also need a small resistor between psus or a small voltage difference could cause power from one supply be dissipated in the other supply with bad results